# Excessive filesystem access due to web crawler seems to break container filesystem

Tags: php, docker

We are running an older PHP e-commerce application on a multi-container (Docker) Elastic Beanstalk setup. On nearly every execution there is data read from/written to a locally stored  (on-instance) cache and an S3 bucket via a stream wrapper.

Usually, this works quite fine. But from time to time when the site is crawled excessively, we see the filesystem break/go corrupt. Either the container’s filesystem goes suddenly *read-only* or we see the error *failed to open stream: Structure needs cleaning* being thrown for cache files.

We’d love to find a way to fix this permanently but have run out of ideas of how to do it. Did anyone ever experience something similar or can explain a possible reason for this behavior?

Comment: consider using a robots.txt directive: crawl-delay: <seconds>

Comment: That's a bug report, not a programming question. That's also where you should look, in the bugtracker of the software you use. For a programming question, you should at least extract a [mcve], both of the Docker setup and of the crawler.

Comment: IF you are talking about static files, have you tried using CDNs?

Comment: This usually happens on small machines. 3 ways to solve it (best when done together): try upgrading it, follow @james suggestion and implement blocking rules on your app server.

Comment: Still, as @UlrichEckhardt said, this is not the proper place for this kind of question.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Obviously, an unintentional wrong-doing in a moment of deep desperation. Sorry!  But thanks a lot for the input anyway!